# LibreOffice Calc: how to highlight row as per cell value?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

In the spreadsheet I want to automatically highlight row once a particular cell value is entered.

I've configured **H** column with list values: [valid,invalid] in *Data*→*Validity*.
The idea is to apply custom *hlt-invalid-bg* style to row where "invalid" value is set in the cell **H**.
I'd like to learn how it can be done using *Format*→*Conditional Formatting* or using any other method.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- Select the whole rows, the conditional format shall apply to.
- Select Format - Conditional Formatting- Condition
- The Dialog "Conditional Formatting for A1:AMJ[n]" is shown. On bottom
  in Range: A1:AMJ[n] is shown.
- In Condition 1 select "Formula is" and input the Formula

  ($H1="invalid")
- In Apply Style select "New Style...". The Dialog "Cell Style" is
  shown.
- In Background tab select a background color.
- Click OK in all Dialogs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to paint all row with a color when the column "B" CONTAINS a value, for example "**XXX**" you can do this:

Format-> Conditional Formatting (Add)

We select "**formula**" and we put: SEARCH("XXX";$B2)>=0

We apply the style "Good" (To view selected rows in green)

And we select the matrix in we want actuate (important!), by example : A2:H109

Now we see all the rows where the **column B** contains "**XXX**" in green.

enjoy !

Comment: Thank you, after 3 threads and 5 answers, this one worked like intended. One a side note, when specifying index "2" as in the answer it would color the rows with offset, so I used index 1.